# how make multiple requests in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of 4 urls and each url has json data. how to loop through urls

ex :
   urls =[ "http://url1.com", 
           "http://url2.com", "http://url3.com", "http://url4.com"];

each url has json one student information like

```
              { date: 08/05/2014
                 studentname: 'xyz'
                 student marks:[
                              maths:80
                              science:60 
                               ]
              }
```

now i want to loop through all 4 urls in this case 4 students information to get all student marks at once(means some thing like all information into one object]so later i can parse and find out which student has got the highest marks or lowest marks ? how this can be done in node.js ?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mikeal/request
https://github.com/caolan/async#map

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

async.map(urls, function(url, callback) {
    request(url, function(err, response, body) {
        callback(err, body);
    })
}, function(err, students){
    if(err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    //Do sth. with students array
});
```

Comment: when i try to loop thru using for(var i =0; i<= students['studentmarks'].length;i++) it says cannot read property of length undefined ?

Comment: Then try to debug it. Maybe `body` is still a JSON string and needs to be parsed.

Comment: i tried this results=JSON.parse(students) and when try to print student names, console.log(results.studentname); it says unexpected token ',' but when i use single url it displays me the name why doesnt work for array of urls ?

Comment: `students` is already an array, there's nothing to parse. Try `callback(err, JSON.parse(body));`

Answer (score 1):

This would solve your problem, use the closure property in javascript. Simple, yet efficient. Just have a function which handles the request part and call that function in the loop. And, leave the rest on the lexical scope of functions and closure property.

```
const request = require("request");

function getTheUrl(data) {
    var options = {
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + data
    }
    return options
}

function consoleTheResult(url) {
    request(url, function (err, res, body) {
        console.log(url);
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    consoleTheResult(getTheUrl(i))
}
```